# Database decimal time covert to date format

Tags: database

In database, a decimal time of **1,407,520,457.84312** is shown.
The actual time is **08/08/2014 17:54:17** 
How can I do the conversion from the decimal form to true time? Thanks

Comment: What database mySQL? MS SQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle?

Comment: mssql database, i cant understand wt is the pattern for the decimal time

Answer (score 0):

Urgh, horrible one, but this seems to work (MYDATE is the field
containing the DECIMAL value):

```
DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR(MYDATE),8),5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'))
```

There must be a more elegant solution though...

Source: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/465990-convert-decimal-date

Comment: the decimal time format is totally different with your source example

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL or MariaDB:

```sql
SELECT left(FROM_UNIXTIME(1407520457.84312),19)
```

> 2014-08-08 17:54:17

```sql
SELECT right(left(FROM_UNIXTIME(1407520457.84312),19),8)
```

> 17:54:17

```sql
SELECT left(FROM_UNIXTIME(1407520457.84312),10)
```

> 2014-08-08